# Storing the return value of multiple threads in an array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I am trying to store the return value of my threads in an array of int pointers and then adding them all up. I am not storing it correctly. Can someone help.

```
pthread_t threads[5];
int *sum;
int *partial_sum[5];
int total = 0;
```

let's assume that my adding function is correct and my thread is returning the correct partial sum

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 *sum = &partial_sum[i];
 pthread_join(threads[i],(void*)&sum);
}

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
 total += *partial_sum[i];
}
printf("%d",total);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
*sum = &partial_sum[i];
pthread_join(threads[i],(void*)&sum);
```

Are wrong. The first problem is that `sum` doesn't point anywhere, so you cant dereference it.

The second problem is that `&partial_sum[i]` is a pointer *to a pointer*, while `*sum` is an `int` value (if `sum` was initialized properly).

You need to make `sum` (which is rather badly named IMO) a pointer to a pointer. And not use dereference when assigning to it:

```
int **sum = &partial_sum[i];
pthread_join(threads[i], (void **) sum);
```

Or simply not create this temporary variable at all:

```
pthread_join(threads[i],(void **) &partial_sum[i]);
```

A very important note: This requires that the thread returns a pointer that is valid even after the thread function ends. In other words, you can't return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: I am using malloc so that it should be fine

Comment: @debiddo Then you must remember to `free` the memory.